# What is the difference in economy between country that uses national currency only and country that uses not only national currency?

Tags: macroeconomics, currency

What is the difference in economy between country that uses national currency only and country that uses not only national currency (for example, national currency + dollar)?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would be there difference in economics (economics is science which studies economy) between two countries like that? Thats like asking what is a difference in physics between country located below sea level like Netherlands and country that is at high elevation like Tibet. Science is everywhere the same.

Comment: @1muflon1 thanks. I made a mistake. I mean economy instead of economics.